# how to call two file in folder i get err file is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest, backend

i made two files user.js and candidate.js in one folder called models how to call both file i try this but get err
const { db } = require('../models/User,Candidate');
what is right way to call two file and also is there some more err?

[dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXft1.png)

## candidate.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const candidateSchema = new Schema({
    candidate_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    party_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    image: {
    type: String,
    required: true}
},
    {
        image: true,
        collection: 'candidate'
    }
);


const candidate = 'candidate';
module.exports = mongoose.model(Candidate, candidateSchema)
```

## server.js i remove middleware code because stackoverflow err

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const Candidate = require('./Candidate');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();

//import routes
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const { db } = require('../models/User,Candidate');

//app
const app = express();

// db
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE,{
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      //useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
   })
  .then(() => console.log('DB Connected'));

app.get("/candidate/get", (req, res) => {
  candidate.find((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  });
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I get it right, you just want to get two models in the same row but it seems impossible. You can import these models like that:

```
const { User } = require('../models/User');
const { Candidate } = require('../models/Candidate');
```

And I see an error from there but I'm not sure, maybe also you should give a try to that too. You exported your Candidate model like that, and used uppercase

```
module.exports = mongoose.model(Candidate, candidateSchema)
```

but you used it in `server.js` with a lowercase and it might be get to fixed too:

```
  ...
  candidate.find((err, data) => {
  ...
```

It seems like it's a possible error.

Let me know if these works out well or not :)